# In Python, how can I send a POST request with URL-Encoded parameters that are 5 nests deep?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, post, urlencode

I would like to send a `POST` request using the `requests` library in Python 3. The only difficulty I am having is in how to embed the urlencoded form part. The raw form looks like:

```
URLEncoded form:                                                                                                                         
data[type]: portion_send
data[attributes][style]: first_style
data[nodes][front][data][id]:1111
data[nodes][back][data][id]:1115
```

The best I have been able to do is to have:

data = {"data":{"attributes":{"style":"first_style"},"nodes":{"front":{"data":{"id":"1111"}},"back":{"data":{"id":"1115"}}},"type":"portion_send"}}

and to embed this inside a `requests.post` function with `params = data`, `params = json.dumps(data)`, and `data = json.dumps(data)`, each to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can put this into a post request? The strange part is that the nesting jumps deeply and it is throwing me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python Requests Module**

I need to know what the error message was to help you with the python `requests` module.

**Using Linux or MacOS Curl`**
If the above fails, you could try this:

```
os.execv('curl -d data=value http://YourWebsite.com')
```

It executes a separate process on your PC. If you run Windows, you could install curl from here: [curl.haxx.se](https://curl.haxx.se/windows).